# Display sql query result in listview JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to display my sql query result in listview in JavaFX. Below is my code which does not display anything in list view, shows blank.

Here observableArrayList() takes argument in list of String like "hello", "all" like wise I passed in it arraylist reference variable. though it is not showing result? where am I wrong?

Code ...

```
 ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<>(10);

    @FXML
    public void dispalyData(){
        String sql = "SELECT cus_id, cus_name, cus_email FROM customer_detail";

        try{
            Connection conn = DataConnect.connect();
            PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
            int i=0;
            while(rs.next()){
            arr.add(rs.getInt("cus_id") +"\t"+ rs.getString("cus_name") 
                              +"\t"+ rs.getString("cus_email"));
            }

            System.out.println(Arrays.asList(arr.toArray()));

        }
        catch(SQLException e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } 
    }



    ObservableList<String> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList(arr);

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        viewlist.setItems(list);
    }
```

Comment: Did you  right write @fxml id ?

Comment: Initialize method works like 'post constructor' method. You init `FXCollections.observableArrayList(arr);` from empty arraylist...`FXCollections.observableArrayList(arr);` doesn't refer `arraylist` and `observablearraylist`, it's only copy elements. You decision -> add items into `observablearraylist`.

Comment: tip :if you don't have reputation, add comments into question paragraph

Answer (score 2):

[`FXCollections.observableArrayList(Collection)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html#observableArrayList-java.util.Collection-) copies the elements of the parameter to the `ObservableList` created. Even if you use [`FXCollections.observableList(List)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html#observableList-java.util.List-) which uses the object passed as parameter as a backing list, modifying the backing list does not trigger change events for the `ObservableList`. `ListView` relies on these events however to update itself...

Work with `list` in your `dispalyData` instead:

```
@FXML
public void dispalyData(){
    String sql = "SELECT cus_id, cus_name, cus_email FROM customer_detail";

    list.clear();
    try{
        Connection conn = DataConnect.connect();
        PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();

        while(rs.next()){
            list.add(rs.getInt("cus_id") +"\t"+ rs.getString("cus_name") 
                          +"\t"+ rs.getString("cus_email"));
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.asList(list.toArray()));

    } catch(SQLException e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } 
}

ObservableList<String> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing `list` before running method `displayData`.
 You need to do this in the method. I suggest you add the following line after the end of your `while` loop.

`list = FXCollections.observableArrayList(arr);`